# Is there a way to get pictures of bosses after defeating them?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I was planning to do a 100% completion run, including a full Hyrule Compendium. About halfway through the game, I realized I never took a picture of my first dungeon boss. I didn't worry too much at first, since you can buy additional pictures in Hateno, but now that I bought every single monster picture available, that boss is still missing (as well as a few others, which I assume to be the final boss and some special enemies I haven't seen yet).

Is there any way to still get a picture of dungeon bosses and complete the compendium? Obviously I don't have any save files from before I fought that boss, and even if I did, I'd have to pretty much re-do the entire game.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will have the opportunity to purchase the missing boss pictures from Symin at the Ancient Hateno Tech Lab.  They will cost 500 rupees each and will only be available *after* you beat the game.  Just look for the Elite Enemy Picture set when buying pictures.

[image]

There's no "New Game+" as of yet but your saves will have a star next to them once the game recognizes that you have beaten the game.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the DLC and haven't beat the illusory realm blight Gannons yet in order to upgrade your hero powers you can take a picture of them for your compendium. That will give you a second chance to photograph those "Elite" enemies if you don't want to buy the pictures.

Comment: I believe you can re-enter all the divine beasts and kill the blights as many times as you want in the DLC.