# Can you revive Master Khoga?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I recently got Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild and have been trying to complete the Hyrule Compendium. I noticed in a YouTube video that Master Khoga is one of the entires, but unfortunately I already killed him. I don't know if you can revive him in some way but I really want to know if you can so I don't have to restart the game. If it matters I'm playing on the Switch version.

Comment: You cannot revive Master Khoga. He's dead permanently once killed. However, this answer explains that it is still possible to get his photo entry by buying it from Symin: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304271/is-there-a-way-to-get-pictures-of-bosses-after-defeating-them